# Random character generator: often vs. rarely occurred character rate

Tags: random-generation

We need to determine if a random character generator function is BAD or not.

With this random character generator, we can create lines with 8 random characters.

We created statistics about the used characters in the file that contains the lines that have 8 random character per line (so the output of the random char generator).

The INPUT for this stat was 20 000 lines. So 20 000 * 8 char = 160 000 characters that should be random.

The stat looks like this (the top is the most often used character in the file, the bottom is the least used):

```
$ cat stat.txt
    OCCURENCE CHAR
    3591 X
    ...
    1230 Y
    $
```

So "X" appeared about 2.9x times more then "Y".

**The Question**: If we are talking about a random number generator, shouldn't it be random, and shouldn't we have **almost the same COUNT of different characters**? Why is there soo much difference between the different character occurrences?

Or was our INPUT too little? What is the INPUT line amount that we can call enough?

**UPDATE**: If we generate not 8, but 16 char long random character lines, the difference is only 1.6x. So the longer the generated characters per line the better the random generator? All the other settings are exactly the same.

**UPDATE2**: This is the script for generating statistics from the password file:

```
sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' pwds.txt | grep -v "^$" | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//; s/ /\t/g' | sed "1s/.*/OCCURENCE\tCHAR/"
```

Explanation for it:

- first it puts a newline after every character
- then it removes the empty lines
- then it sorts it
- then the "uniq -c" counts the occurence of the characters
- "sort -rn" sorts the occurence table, biggest on top
- the sed with "\t": removes unneeded spaces from the start of every line then it removes all the spaces and puts tab instead
- then it puts an "OCCURENCE\tCHAR" line in the first line of the stat

**UPDATE3:** This generator is a random password generator, that's why it's important that it should have really random characters in it.

**UPDATE4:** "how many different characters are the 8 characters selected from?" -> **the charset is 74 different one**

Comment: The update makes no sense to me: whether you put 8 or 16 characters on a line, if you *start with the same seed* and generate 160000 characters you will get exactly the same characters as before and therefore should obtain the same counts. If you're not starting with the same seed and generating the same numbers of characters, then you are varying too many things to allow for straightforward comparisons between the two scenarios. (Regardless, either your generator is strongly non-uniform or else there is a bug in the code that tallies the character counts.)

Comment: Generating the stats are the exact same code and not very complex, updated the question with it in UPDATE2

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test

Comment: *How* you happen to count your characters is of no concern here. What we can say at this point is however you came by these counts, they do not reflect characters that were generated uniformly and independently at random. There's no way we can tell you *why* you are observing the variations you are.

Comment: "they do not reflect characters that were generated uniformly and independently at random" -> that is the question. For us, it looks like this random character generator isn't very random, since there is a stable 2.9x difference between the mostly used character and the most rarely used char, the occurence should be more.. similar..

Comment: how many different characters are the 8 characters selected from?

Comment: I answered it in UPDATE4